# How come that someone understands an utterance only after a few moments?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

I have seen and experienced the following phenomena. It often happen in a work environment but can happen anytime and anywhere:

1) Person A is doing something that requires full concentration (like reading or thinking deeply).

2) Person B suddenly ask/say something to Person A

3) Person A replied with "What do you say?" or "Pardon please" (or something similar, as if he/she doesn't hear what person B said) after some brief pause/delay.

4) Person B didn't answer back (optional)

5) Person A answers/responses (before Person B repeats what he/she said) to Person B (as if he/she heard it fully)

Is there a psychological term that describes/explain it? How it is happening? What is its effect with the brain of Person A if there is?

P.S.
I don't know what is the right tag for it.

Comment: I think this is described as being as a result the amount of time auditory memories are preserved. So, you might want to tag this with "memory".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you describe can be explained by [echoic memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echoic_memory) and [working memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_memory).

> **Echoic memory** is one of the sensory memory registers; a component of
>   sensory memory (SM) that is specific to retaining auditory
>   information. The sensory memory for sounds that people have just
>   perceived is the form of echoic memory. ... This particular sensory store is capable of storing large amounts of
>   auditory information that is only retained for a short period of time
>   (3–4 seconds). This echoic sound resonates in the mind and is replayed
>   for this brief amount of time shortly after the presentation of
>   auditory stimuli.

.

> **Working memory,** a core executive function, is a cognitive memory
>   buffer with a limited capacity that is responsible for the transient
>   holding, processing, and manipulation of information. Working
>   memory is an important process for reasoning and the guidance of
>   decision making and behavior.

.

Person A is fully concentrated and his working memory capacity is full, so he does not pay attention to what the other person is saying. But when person A asks "What do you say?", working memory resources are released and attention is diverted to the echoic memory which replays what person B said.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, everyone has experienced such situation, although only a few people pay attention to this.

It is a usual human behaviour. People do ask about your question to get some time for thinking what to answer. Furthermore, this behaviour is very common among journalists, because this may be a way to avoid answering the question.

In addition, there is another reason. A person who is asking feels more confidence. Thus, people may ask again to bring the situation under their own control.